# OnOptionsItemSelected not called in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am newbie to Xamarin.Forms. I am trying to show a `DisplayAlert()` when **NavigationBar back button** is clicked. I have tried implementing according to [this article](https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/lets-override-navigation-bar-back-button-click-in-xamarin-forms/). The problem is when I click on the button the popup doesn't come. I placed a breakpoint on `OnOptionsItemSelected()` method to see if its getting called or not, it doesn't. This is my MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{ 
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
    global::Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, bundle);
    LoadApplication(new App());

    Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
    SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    
}

public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{   
    //Placed a debugger here
    // check if the current item id is equals to the back button id
    if (item.ItemId == 16908332)
    {
        // retrieve the current xamarin forms page instance
        var currentpage = Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault() as NavBackButtonContentPage;

        // check if the page has subscribed to the custom back button event
        if (currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction != null)
        {
            // invoke the Custom back button action
            currentpage?.CustomBackButtonAction.Invoke();
            // and disable the default back button action
            return false;
        }

        // if its not subscribed then go ahead with the default back button action
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    else
    {
        // since its not the back button click, pass the event to the base
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I am using it inside `MasterDetailPage`.

Comment: Why not just do it in pcl using pop up?

Comment: there is an option to do it on pcl using OnDisapperaing(), the issue is that by the time it asks for the response it already goes to the lastpage

Comment: There is a onbackpressed event you should check out in contentpage

Comment: thats for physical button plz read my question. i want it for navigationbar back button

Comment: Have you checked this? https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/lets-override-navigation-bar-back-button-click-in-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thats the article i referred

Comment: Did you try to restart vs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same issue and found the solution. The issue is `MainActivity` was sub-classing from the `FormsAppCompactActivity` instead of old `FormsApplicationActivity` which was the previous parent class for `MainActivity`. So assume bug on new `FormsAppCompactActivity`

The issue will be fixed when you add following lines to `MainActivity` OnCreate method (after the  `LoadApplication(new App());` line)

```
Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar 
                = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Referenced URL and thread as follows 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/218663

https://theconfuzedsourcecode.wordpress.com/2017/03/02/formsappcompatactivity-is-not-calling-onoptionsitemselected-xamarin-android/

Comment: This seems to no longer be working. SetSupportActionBar expects a parameter of type AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar and it won't work with Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar.
Also if I use the AndroidX Toolbar instead of the V7 Toolbar it still won't work.

Comment: @ChristophMett were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I "solved" it by disabling the back button and putting a custom control into the `NavigationPage.TitleView`. Here you can see how I've done this: https://gist.github.com/cytoph/1d311de69ed51358cc25b726cb7cc19a 

DISCLAIMER: the UI was only tested to look good (hence native) on Android, for iOS other margins, etc. will most likely be necessary.

Comment: Looked into this once again and the above code would now written as follows:

`var toolbar = FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);`
`SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Problem is, even with this `OnOptionsItemSelected` won't be called 

Answer (score 2):

[isaman kumara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5281453/isaman-kumara)'s comment from 2019-06-01 said the following:

> The issue will be fixed when you add following lines to MainActivity
> OnCreate method (after the LoadApplication(new App()); line)
>
> Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar
> = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
> SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

One of the responses said this:

> This seems to no longer be working. SetSupportActionBar expects a
> parameter of type AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar and it won't work
> with Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar.

I was able to get OnOptionsItemSelected working again in Xamarin Forms 4.8 by adding this to the MainActivity's OnCreate method after the LoadApplication line:

```
if (FindViewById(Resource.Id.toolbar) is AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar)
{
    SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Apologies for not commenting directly to the earlier comment, but I don't have enough reputation points to do so.

Comment: What namespace is your 'Resource' from?

Comment: @Edgaras: It should be from your project e.g. *MyProjectName.Droid.Resource*

Comment: What styles/themes are you using? `SupportActionBar` is `AndroidX.AppCompat.App.ActionBar` in my case ...

Comment: The above solution didn't fully worked for me. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66020150/426227) I did find the missing parts.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but you can track the `OnPopViewAsync` event through a `NavigationRenderer` like this:

```cs
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationRenderer))]
namespace YourApp.Droid
{
    public class CustomNavigationRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
    {
        public CustomNavigationRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<bool> OnPopViewAsync(Page page, bool animated)
        {
            // Write your code here
        }
    }
}
```

Using this code, you can capture both events in the same place in Android, the hardware back button and the NavigationBar back button pressed.

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for the hardware back button for me so OnBackPressed in the Activity is the only method I could get to work. This works great for the soft back button though.

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't created an event for triggering.
In an contentpage you want to override the back button, try this:

```
            this.CustomBackButtonAction = async () =>
            {
                var result = await this.DisplayAlert(null,
                    "Hey wait now! are you sure " +
                    "you want to go back?",
                    "Yes go back", "Nope");

                if (result)
                {
                    await Navigation.PopAsync(true);
                }
            };
```

You will then get the event and a popup asking if you really, really want to go back.

Comment: I have implemented this event and still its not getting triggered