# OnOptionsItemSelected not called in xamarin froms - AndroidX

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-toolbar

I'm working with a Xamarin Forms project and I'm trying to override the default behavior of the Navigation Bar Back Button in order to run my own navigation service.

My MainActivity derives from **FormsAppCompatActivity**

Previously the working solution was adding the following lines in the **OnCreate** and **OnOptionsItemSelected** methods :

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    { 
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        if (item.ItemId != Android.Resource.Id.Home) return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);

        return !UseINavigationService() && base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

This seems to no longer be working. **SetSupportActionBar** expects a parameter of type AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar and it won't work with Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar. Also if I use the AndroidX Toolbar instead of the V7 Toolbar it still won't work.

Anyone faced similar issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AndroidX replaces the Android support libraries, and so any references to Android support library types must be replaced with references to AndroidX types.

You could do like below:

in your **MainActivity** `OnCreate()` method:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        //ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
        AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

then in your **ToolBar.xaml** change the `Android.Support.V7.Widget` namespace to `AndroidX.AppCompat.Widget`:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
  android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>
```

Comment: already tried this and didn't work. The only thing I hadn't done is comment out TabLayoutResource and ToolbarResource in the beginning but even after doing that it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @i_ll_be_back what's your Xamarin.Forms version ?I test on v5.0.0.1931,it works.

Comment: your answer works at Xamarin.Forms v5.0.0, I was using 4.8. But the problem still remains when I make an internal Navigation through a MasterDetail Page. When I navigate from the Detail Page then it stops working. But your solution did fix the initial part so I'm accepting it

Comment: @i_ll_be_back: I also use a `MasterDetailPage` and when navigating back via soft back button `OnOptionsItemSelected` is not called. Did you found a solution for this? I [read](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3894) that there doesn't really seem to be a solution for this :-(